# Check if linked list was initialized

Tags: c, linked-list, deque

problem is, when I call function `initDeque` to create deque, function have to check if deque was already initialized. My thought was having variable `bool isInit` in deque's structure and check if `isInit` is true(initiated) / false(not initiated). But the problem is, if I call `initDeque` more than one time, it initiates deque again. Here's the code:

```
int initDeque(deque *d){ //Create new deque
    d = (deque*)malloc(sizeof(deque));
    if ((d->isInit)==false){

        if (!d) {
            perror("malloc");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        d->isInit=true;
        d->front=NULL;
        d->rear=NULL;
        return d;
    } else {
        printf("Deque is already initialized!");
    }
}
```

and the struct:

```
typedef struct{
    link front;
    link rear;
    bool isInit;
}deque;
```

My thought is that when I allocate memory in the first place, it removes all data stored in `front; rear; isInit;`. What should I do?

Comment: Just because you allocate space for a struct, does not mean it is set. You must first set the values within your 'd' structure.  Also, something seems fishy about calling !d. Are you coming from a PHP background?  Edit* Oh I see, yes, when you call malloc again you are creating a new pointer, so references to the old d are lost within the scope of this function.

Comment: The instruction `d = (deque*)malloc(sizeof(deque));` overwrites the previous content of d with a pointer to an uninitialized buffer. Then you test `d->isInit` ! How can this work ? Return is also bogus.

Comment: I mean when I call the function again and it allocates memory for `d`, doesn't it wipe all data and set it to `NULL` and `false`? And no, C is my first language.

Comment: What do you want this function to do ?

Comment: Firstly, to check if this function was called in the program, allocate memory  for deque and set primitive data to deque's variables.

Comment: Why would you call initDeque on an initialized deque ? What is an unitialized deque ? d would have the value NULL I guess. So instead of using the isInit boolean you should test d against NULL to detect an unitialized deque.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
deque* initDeque(deque *d){ //Create new deque
    if(d == NULL){
       d = (deque*)malloc(sizeof(deque));
       d->isInit = false;
    }
    if ((d->isInit)==false){ 
        if (!d) {
            perror("malloc");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        d->isInit=true;
        d->front=NULL;
        d->rear=NULL;
    } else 
        printf("Deque is already initialized!");
    return d;
}
```

As has been mentioned in many places on this post, this is a weird implementation.

Normally with this kind of data structure you'd have create(), destroy(deque *d), queue(deque *d), dequeue(deque *d) functions.

At the top of each function you'd have a NULL check (except for create)

Comment: You should move the `if (!d)` bloc just after the malloc.

Comment: doesn't work like that, gives me an error at `if ((d->isInit)==false){ }`

Comment: @RimantasRadžiūnas What are you passing in as a parameter? Also, what error?

Comment: in `main()` I declare `deque *d;` and pass it to `initDeque(d)`. Running the program, it just crashes without any explanation. Debugging the program, it shows that error is in this line without any explanation.

Comment: @RimantasRadžiūnas You should declare deque *d = NULL. It is bad practice to not initialize your variables

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem! Thank you!

Comment: @RimantasRadžiūnas Just to make sure, do you understand why you were having problems? It is important, especially when learning, to see where your mistake was.

Comment: I think `deque *d` could get not NULL, but any trash data left before at that memory block. Am I right?

Comment: @RimantasRadžiūnas Since *d was not initialized, the initDeque() function was not detecting it as null, so assumed it had been created. It then tried to check its isInit value, which did not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize the deque when you create it. There is no need to reinitialize it.

```
deque * newDeque(){ //Create new deque
    deque* d = malloc(sizeof(deque));
    if (!d) {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    d->isInit=true; // not needed anymore
    d->front=NULL;
    d->rear=NULL;
    return d;
}
```

In case you really want your initDeque function, here is a suggested implementation

```
deque * initDeque(deque * d){ //Create new deque if needed
    if (d == NULL) {
        deque* d = malloc(sizeof(deque));
        if (!d) {
            perror("malloc");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        d->front=NULL;
        d->rear=NULL;
    }
    return d;
}
```